# SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED

Tags: java, android, xml

Actually I'm building an application which requires user's location. But I'm getting **SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED** error. Following are my **MainActivity.java** and **AndroidManifest.xml** files:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
TextView lat, lon;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private double latitude, longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    lon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, connectionResult.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    lat.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
    lon.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(longitude));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.harshil.location">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is what logcat says:

```
D/MainActivity: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
```

So, How to get through this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing following line [in **build.gradle**] from:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

So, the problem is I am using **higher version** of **Google Play Service** for development than that installed on **my device** or **emulator**.

I came to my solution as follow: 
**1.** I checked to update **Google Play Service** on my device but it says it is **up-to-date**. 
**2.** I checked in **App Manager** to see the version of it, and I came to know that it is actually at 9.8.77. So I changed play-service version from **10.0.1** to **9.8.0**. 
Now, I am out of this problem. 
**Thank you.**

Comment: I have this problem using gms:play-services:16.0.1 but if I try to move back to version 11.8.0 gradle complains with the ERROR: All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0

Answer (score -3):

Download the the google play store in your mobile and check it .for me i was not  installed google play store in my mobile now i installed google play store ,its working fine.

Comment: Could you improve your answer? I do not understand what you mean.